# How can i use this code in my Mapper and Reducer ? i want run this code in Google cluster

Tags: python, python-3.x, hadoop, google-cloud-platform, mapreduce

In this code I have generated the random numbers and then take a Probability of that numbers and finalize with histogram. but now i want to run this code in mapreduce. how can i create the mapper.py and reducer.py ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter

def my_funct():
   #Random Number Generating
   x = np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=100000)
   #np.random.seed(1223) # fixing the seed
   counts = Counter(x)
   total = sum(counts.values())
   d1 = {k:v/total for k,v in counts.items()}
   grad = d1.keys()
   prob = d1.values()
   print(str(grad))
   print(str(prob))
   #bins = 20
   plt.hist(prob,bins=20, normed=1, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5)
   #plt.plot(bins, hist, 'r--')
   plt.xlabel('Probability')
   plt.ylabel('Number Of Students')
   plt.title('Histogram of Students Grade')
   plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15)

   plt.show()
#calling the function twice
my_funct()
#my_funct()
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is quite a broad question.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin i want use this code in mapreduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use matplotlib in mapreduce. It has no GUI to show you results